# CIDER with the Macchiato-Framework on Server and Browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, emacs, clojurescript, cider

I'm trying to setup CIDER for a [macchiato](https://macchiato-framework.github.io/)-project for the back- and frontend. `lein new macchiato dumac +browser` gives me quite an [intricate `project.clj`](https://pastebin.com/mSywFyQN) with various profiles, among which I find `:browser-dev` and `:dev` (for the server side).

Now, whenever I do `cider-jack-in-ClojureScript` CIDER defaults to a `:dev`-profile, but seemingly not the one defined in the `profiles.clj` since the Node-script is not launched (line 47). I can happily code away on the server side though once I dispatch the node command manually.

Still I have no idea as to how I may start a REPL for the browser from within Emacs (I can do so by manually typing `lein build-browser` at the terminal but I cannot connect to that nREPL even if I replace the cider-nrepl dependencies). Here's a line from the [CIDER Docs](https://docs.cider.mx/cider/cljs/figwheel.html#_using_legacy_figwheel_leiningen_only) on how to use legacy figwheel (as the macchiato tmaplate does)… it may indicate the problem:

> make sure `:cljsbuild` and `:figwheel` settings are in the root of
>   your Leiningen project definition.

Macchiato's template `project.clj` obviously doesn't conform to this requirement as these settings are nested within the profiles. **Does that mean that the template is incompatible with CIDER? Would transitioning to fighwheel-main help?** (I have no clue on how to do this with such an intricate project.clj.)

**Has anyone gotten Macchiato to work with CIDER on the server and browser?**

I'm kinda overwhelmed right now and would be most grateful for any clues as to what I may try next

Thanks!

Oliver

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfortunately late to this question, but this is actually quite easy using `shadow-cljs`, and does what you want: allows live REPL access to the server and/or browser JS runtimes.

Include `macchiato/core` in `:dependencies`, and have a build target for the server, and a build target for the browser. Launch e.g. `shadow-cljs watch server browser`, then use `cider-connect` / `cider-connect-cljs` once you have a node or browser process connected to the runtime.